# Angular 10 Load SVG Dynamically Without IMG or OBJECT Tags

Tags: html, angular, svg, httpclient, element

I'm working on a simplified way to load SVG files without using IMG or OBJECT tags as it impedes my ability to control fill colors through external CSS. Using inline SVG is ideal, but with so many components using repeated icons, it's a lot of maintenance and I'd prefer to centralize them in their .svg file format. I thought about just making each one their own component, but that means there's a component.ts file I don't need for each one, and it might be a little confusing or other developers.

So far, creating a custom element that pulls the svg location from a "src" attribute is working:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-svg',
    template: `
        <ng-template>
            {{ src }}
        </ng-template>
        <span [innerHTML]="svg"></span>
    `
})
export class SvgComponent implements OnInit {
    svg: SafeHtml = '';
    @Input() public src = '';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private sanitize: DomSanitizer) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.http.get(this.src, {responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(svg => {
            this.svg = this.sanitize.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(svg);
        });
    }
}
```

Then I use my custom element in another component.html:

```
<app-svg src="assets/test.svg"></app-svg>
```

The result of course is an inline SVG with an inline element as a wrapper:

```
<app-svg src="assets/test.svg" ng-reflect-source="assets/test.svg">
   <span>
      <svg>
         <path d="...">
      </svg>
   </span>
</app-svg>
```

I suppose this is harmless enough, but it's a little annoying and there's unnecessary extra markup. Ideally, I'd want to have the innerHTML applied to APP-SVG, but that means the svg in the binding would need to exist outside of the TS for for the custom element due to scoping issues. It's also messy having to remember to include [innerHTML] on every APP-SVG tag. I've tried using [outerHTML] on the SPAN tag in the template, but I get a runtime error saying there is no parent container element.

So, my question is can this work?:

1. Replace the  in the template with the loaded SafeHtml? Or,
2. Apply the loaded SafeHtml as the innerHTML of the selector in the SvgComponent TS? Or,
3. Use <svg [innerHTML]="svg"> as part of the template instead of SPAN, but remove the parent SVG from the loaded SafeHtml before applying it to the innerHTML? Or,
4. Is there something in NPM that already does what I'm trying to create?

I wish they made this easier. Any advice or explanation as to why this won't work would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Naturally, as SOON as I post my question, I trip over the solution. The trick is to use ElementRef so that I can target the selector's innerHTML, and I don't have to use DomSanitizer to do it. The new code looks as follows (including imports this time):

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-svg',
    template: `
        <ng-template>
            {{ src }}
        </ng-template>
    `
})
export class SvgComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() public src = '';

    constructor(
        private el: ElementRef,
        private http: HttpClient,
    ) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.http.get(this.src, {responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(svg => {
            this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML = svg;
        });
    }
}
```

If you don't want to have app-svg as a container, you can use instead:

```
this.el.nativeElement.outerHTML = svg;
```

And it will replace app-svg with he loaded svg. Hope this helps anyone else trying to accomplish the same thing. Cheers!

Comment: Be very cautions with this approach.
Inserting a random text from the backend, without a good way to check its validity is not very safe. Manipulating the DOM directly, without any protection also exposes several risks. You should consider using the Renderer2 to insert the content, as per the official doc.